# Translating set syntax in FOL

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Even though the formal syntax rules for first order logic talk about $\forall x$ or $\exists x$ without necessarily including any kind of $\in Y$ part for some domain/set $Y$, sometimes we'll see things like $\forall x \in \mathbb{N}$ for example and I was unsure where that syntax "comes in" to FOL.

In a comment on another question I was told that:

$\forall x\in Y, P(x)$ is just convenient shorthand for $\forall x(x\in Y\to P(x))$

$\exists x\in Y, P(x)$ is just convenient shorthand for $\exists x(x\in Y\land P(x))$

However I don't understand how we determine whether we need the $\to$ symbol or the $\land$ symbol. In particular why isn't it $\land$ for both, or $\to$ for both, etc? How do we know which to use in which situation?

Comment: See [Restricted quantifiers](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Restricted_quantifier).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So if we wished to negate these quantifiers, they would be equivalent to $\lnot \forall n (n \in \mathbb N \to (n \ge 0)) = \exists n(n \in \mathbb{N} \land (n < 0))$ and $\lnot \exists n (n \in \mathbb N \land (n = 0)) = \forall n(n \not\in \mathbb{N} \lor (n \neq 0))$?

Comment: Exactly; they are simply first-order logic formulas, Thus, the usual rules regarding quantifiers and connectives apply.

Comment: @ MauroALLEGRANZA First one saying: It's not true that for all natural numbers n, they must be greater than or equal to zero. Instead, there exists some natural number that is less than zero. Second one saying: It's not true that there exists a natural number equal to 0. Instead, for all n, it's either not a natural number, or it's not equal to 0? I don't quite understand the intuition of the second one here. Did I negate it correctly? Why not "for all natural numbers, they're not equal to 0"

Comment: But $∀n(n∉ \mathbb N ∨ (n≠0))$ and $∀n(n \in \mathbb N \to (n≠0))$ are the same ... :-)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  Oh man! You're right. That makes sense now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider as domain of the interpretation the set of [*integers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer), and let the [*naturals*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) defines as the non-negative integers.

We have that "Every *natural* numbers is non negative" will be : $∀n(\text {Nat}(n) → (n ≥ 0))$ or equivalently : $∀n(n ∈ \mathbb N → (n ≥ 0))$.

What happens with $\land$ instead of $\to$ ?

We have that : $∀n(\text {Nat}(n) \land (n ≥ 0))$ will be false, because e.g. $\text {Nat}(-1) \land (-1 ≥ 0)$ is false.

$\text {Nat}(-1) → (-1 ≥ 0)$ instead, is true.

---

Consider now "There is a negative *natural* number", that is obviously false.

It will be : $\exists n(\text {Nat}(n) \land (n \lt 0))$ or equivalently : $\exists n(n ∈ \mathbb N \land (n \lt 0))$.

What happens with $\to$ instead of $\land$ ?

We have that $\exists n(\text {Nat}(n) \to (n \lt 0))$ will be true, because $\text {Nat}(-1) \to (-1 \lt 0)$ is true.

Comment: But syntactically why must we not have any false statements in a $\forall$ but we can have them in an $\exists$? Intuitively I understand why but syntactically I don't see where. Like if we were writing $\exists n(\text {Nat}(n) \land (n = 0))$ the inner conjunction would be false for e.g. $n = 1$ because $\text {Nat}(n)$ is true but $n = 0$ is false. How do we know that some false statements are OK but others are not? Or some true statements are OK, but others are not?

Comment: @user525966 - "some false statements are OK but others are not?" What does it mean ? We want to translate in symbols statements of natural language and mathematics. What I'm saying is : we have mathematical statements about numbers with their respective truth valuse: some are true and some are false. If we translate a true one with a formula that has not the same truth value, that translation is incorrect.